# How to display icons in a table depending on model in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS (and Javascript as well) and I try to display different icons in a table depending on a value in a field from my model.

Let's say this is my model:

$scope.MyList = [{ name: "Production", status: "Running"},
            { name: "Test", status: "Stopped"}];

This is a table for displaying the model in one of my views:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in MyList">
            <td>{{instance.name}}</td>
            <td>{{instance.status}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to display the status using both one icon and the text. What is the recommended way of doing it? I would like to use something that feels natural with AngularJS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from dolgishev pointed me into the right direction.

I initialice my table elements like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in itemList">
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td class="{{item.status}}">{{item.status}}</td>
</tr>
```

and then I use CSS for displaying the icon using a font from FontAwesome. This is for example the CSS for the state 'Running':

```
.Running:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size:1.3em;
    color:green;
    content: '\f00c';  /* the ok icon */
    padding-right: 4px; /* plus 4px spacing */
}
```

This will display the ok icon in green, then 4 pixel padding and then the text for the state "Running". It is looking great!

Answer (score 0):

For solve this you can use Angular's directive ng-class. It allows you to set class of element depend on expression.
Also you can do this without directive, in this way:

```
<div class="{{MyList.name}}">
```